# How is loading of a direct mapped cache done when block size > size of data?

Tags: caching

I have a direct mapped cache that looks like this:

25 bits tag, 4 bits set, 3 bits byte offset

Every set has a data size of 8 bytes (block size = 8 bytes).

Let's say that I have two ints, x and y, next to each other, with these memory addresses:

```
some-tag set  boff
         0000 000 x
         0000 100 y
```

Clearly x and y go into the same set, now here's my question:

When I read x (and it's a cache miss) then x is put into the first 4 bytes of a cache set, is y also put into the latter 4 bytes to fill up the entire block of that cache set?

I believe this to be the case, since otherwise you'd get the wrong value when you read y and find a matching tag in the cache set.

**The thing I'm confused about is this:** When I read y and it's a cache miss, is the previous 4 bytes in  memory also read in to fill up the block? Surely it must be, because otherwise reading x would lead to a cache hit with invalid data returned.